# Moving range of cells if a cell in the same row contain "TEXT"

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I need to move a range of cells in each row (scanned) that contains a cell in a specific column (could be any column in  my case, but in my code it is colomn "E") which value start by the text string **l**. Here is what I've tried (I'm new to VBA). In this case I want to move `Ji:Mi` to `Ki:Ni`, where `i` is row number.

```
Sub Move2()
    For i = 48 To 31 Step -1
        If Range("E" & i) = "*l" Then
            Range("J" & i & ":" & "M" & i).Cut
            Range("K" & i & ":" & "N" & i).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [*Like Operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) like this:

```
Sub Move2()
    For i = 48 To 31 Step -1
        If Range("E" & i) Like "l*" Then
            Range("J" & i & ":" & "M" & i).Cut _
            Range("K" & i & ":" & "N" & i)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Above code specifically looks for **l** and will ignore **L**.
If you need to include both, use this line for the `If`. HTH.

```
If Range("E" & i) Like "[Ll]*" Then
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the Like operator is useful. I had a mistake in "Step 1" which I changed to "Step -1". Corrected.

Comment: @NeuroBM Ah Ok. I'll leave the answer here anyways :). Adjusted my code as well :D. And forget about using *Select* in most cases. [Check this cool post out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). Also this [link](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jonskeet/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) for accepting answer in case someone answers your question which satisfies your needs :D